# Getting all the webpages of a SPWeb and subwebs that have a field with a value in Sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have a website in Sharepoint 2007. I want to make a query where the field "home" of the webpages is equal to 1 in one specific SPWeb and (this is the important part) its sub-SPwebs.
I can make this work with the site in question and not with the subsites. That is to say: It is not recursive but I indicate it in the "webs scope='recursive'" clause.

I include also the List I want to use, that is to say, the pages (not documents, master pages or whatever) this is whay i look for the "850" basetemplate (the one for pages).

The code I am using is this (i have tried with other methods with the same query and the result is the same):

> ```
>   string campo="home";
>   SPSiteDataQuery qry = new SPSiteDataQuery();
>
>                   qry.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='";
>                   qry.Query += campo + "'/><Value
> ```

```
Type='Boolean'>1</Value></Eq>";
```

> ```
>                   qry.Query += "</Where><OrderBy><FieldRef
> ```
>
> Name='Modified' Ascending='false'> />";

```
                  qry.Webs = "<Webs Scope='Recursive'/>";
```

> ```
>                   qry.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='Title'/><FieldRef
> ```
>
> Name='Modified'/>";
>
> ```
>  //this gives me system privileges
>                   using (SPSite site = new SPSite(CurrentSite.ID,
> ```
>
> GetSystemToken(CurrentSite)))
>                         {
>
> ```
>                       using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb("/News/"))
>                       {
>
>                           StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
>
>                           sb.Append("<Lists>");
>
>                           foreach (SPList list in web.Lists)
>                           {
>
>                               if (list.BaseTemplate.ToString() ==
> ```
>
> "850")
>                                     {
>
> ```
>                                   sb.Append("<List ID=\"" +
> ```
>
> list.ID.ToString() + "\"/>");
>
> ```
>                               }
>
>                           }
>
>                           sb.Append("</Lists>");
>                           qry.Lists = sb.ToString();
>
>                           dt = web.GetSiteData(qry);
>
>                       ..................
> ```

So, the only solution I found was to make a loop after the precedent code through the Webs but i don't think this is a very optimized way:

```
     foreach (SPWeb w2 in web.Webs)
                              {
                                 sb = new StringBuilder();
                                      sb.Append("<Lists>");
                                      foreach (SPList list in w2.Lists)


                           {
                                              if (list.BaseTemplate.ToString() 
== "850")
                                              {

      sb.Append("<List ID=\""
     + list.ID.ToString() + "\"/>");
                                              }
                                          }


                                      sb.Append("</Lists>");
                                              qry.Lists = sb.ToString();

                                          DataTable dttmp = w2.GetSiteData(qry);
                                          if (dttmp != null
 && dttmp.Rows.Count > 0)
                                          {
                                              dt.Merge(dttmp);
                                          }

                                  w2.Dispose();
                              }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I did the following, i don't know what has worked finally, i have changed the way I ask the Lists and i have included RowLimit:

DataTable dt = null;
        DataView dv = null;

```
    SPSiteDataQuery qry = new SPSiteDataQuery();

    qry.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='";
    qry.Query += campo + "'/><Value Type='Boolean'>1</Value></Eq>";
    qry.Query += "</Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Modified' Ascending='false' /></OrderBy>";
    qry.Webs = "<Webs Scope='Recursive'/>";
    qry.Lists = "<Lists ServerTemplate='850' Hidden='FALSE' MaxListsLimit='50'/>";
    qry.RowLimit = 3;

    qry.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='Title'/><FieldRef Name='Modified'/><FieldRef Name='FileRef'/>";

    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(CurrentSite.ID, GetSystemToken(CurrentSite)))
    {
        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(webUrl))
        {   
            dt = web.GetSiteData(qry);

            dv = dt.DefaultView;

        }
    }

    return dv;
```

Comment: Glad you got things up and running! Oh, and thanks for posting the working code.

Answer (score 1):

You talk about setting the webs scope to recursive, but in your (ill-formatted) example code you leave the webs property blank, meaning the site data query will only search through the specified web.

This specific (omitted) detail of your code is *very* important, because making even the slightest spelling mistake in the innerXML specification will silently revert the behaviour back to the default, meaning only the current web will be searched. A typical pitfall would be getting the capitalization wrong in either Webs or Scope.

For the record, the correct way of specifying this is

```
qry.Webs = "<Webs Scope='Recursive' />";
```

As a quick check, you can try setting the scope to SiteCollection, see if that works.

**[Edit]** Agreed, now your Webs property shows up it seems fine :-). Have you tried setting the Nullable='TRUE' attribute in the fieldref of the Campo field? If the field isn't present (or corrupted or whatever) in any of the subsites, that might help. **[/Edit]**

Comment: Sorry, but it is the editor that has hidden the part that seemed ill-formatted. I tried SiteCollection too.

Comment: Thanks for you help, i did something different at the end, don't ask me what exactly made this work.